# Java Map with multiple primitive keys

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm looking to have a map in Java/LibGDX which can take multiple primitive values as key. My concrete case is that I have multiple position (x,y,z) which need an object attached.

At the moment I am using an (Object)Map with a List as key, but isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is *no*, because primitive types can't be Java Map keys. The longer answer to your question is *easily*, make a `Position` class -

```
static class Position {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
  Position(int x, int y, int z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
  public boolean equals(Object b) {
    if (b instanceof Position) {
      Position other = (Position) b;
      return this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y && this.z == other.z;
    }
    return false;
  }
  public int hashCode() {
    return (Integer.valueOf(x).hashCode() ^ Integer.valueOf(y)
        .hashCode()) & Integer.valueOf(z).hashCode();
  }
}
```

Then

```
Map<Position, Object> map;
```

Comment: Of course this will need overrides for `equals` and `hashCode` to work as a map key.

Comment: Strangly, I get a heap overflow using your code. If I use List<Integer>, I do not.